# Huge increase in Facebook traffic are there facebook analytics to see how people found us ?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, analytics

We've got a company facebook page, we rarly update it, or engage with our audience, but today i went on to google analytics for our company website, and saw this [image].

To put this into perspective we usually get between 1 and 0 people coming through facebook each day to our site.

Along with the increase in traffic we got a large increase in likes, we have no idea who these people are, or why so many people have visited our FB page and then clicked on our website. (i recon about 6000 people must have been on our FB page today, baring in mind that only a small % of them would then click though to our company website.)

Does facebook have built in analytics to :

1. Stat's ie how many page view our company page has had today
2. a referals view ti see were these people came from

Is this real or could it be a malicious bot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook exposes analytics for pages with [Page Insights](https://www.facebook.com/help/pages/insights). The **Reach** page (`https://www.facebook.com/<pagename>/page_insights_reach`) includes information about how many page views your page gets each day, and a list of external referrers.

Comment: thanks, just a side note you need 30+ likes to be able to access these features fully

Comment: do you know if theres a way to see internal refers ie. from which facebook page they found you ?